# Prevent unnecessary redraws in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with a few thousand rows in React where the content never changes (some rows may be filtered away, but row contents are never updated). Each row has a checkbox to select it and then trigger some further action on the selected row. A naïve implementation of this might set a state that contains IDs of all the selected elements and then each checkbox will get its checked property based on if its ID is in the state:

```
const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState(new Set());
...
return (
  <Table>
  ...
    <Table.Row>
    ...
      <Checkbox id={entry.id} checked={selectedIds.has(entry.id)} onClick={onCheckboxClick} />
```

The problem with this is that any change to `selectedIds` causes redraw of the entire table, even if only 1 row was selected. This can be easily fixed by using `React.memo()` on row level, here's my implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-row-with-checkbox-semantic-lki3x

With this, selecting any single row is fast, only that row will be redrawn. But if we click the checkbox in the table header that (un)selects all the rows, it becomes slow again because now all the rows have to be redrawn even though only a checkbox in a 1 cell has changed.

If we decouple the individual checkbox checked state from the `selectedIds`, it becomes super fast: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-row-with-checkbox-semantic-tqiqi (only change is in index.js)

What is the correct React way of solving this problem? Do I need to use `React.memo()` on cell level instead of row level? I'm looking for a general fix that can be implemented in `DataTable` rather than something limited to this case.